# R output to txt file

Tags: r, output

I have a data frame in 2 columns

```
userID itemID
1       101
1       103
1       107
2       102
2       103
3       104  
...
```

The output I want is to write a file to result.txt
1  \t  101 , 103 , 107
2  \t  102 , 103
3  \t  104
here \t means a tab distance between userID and the itemID. This is not as aligned as a table. I am more of Java and Python background, what are the lower level writing commands in R for general purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use dplyr package for this

```
library(dplyr)

df.summary <- df %.%
  group_by(userId) %.%
  summarise(itemId = paste(itemId, collapse = ","))


write.table(x=df.summary,file='new_file.tsv',sep='\t',row.names=F)
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit messy, but this will do the trick, writing the output to `output.txt`:

```
d <- read.table(text='userID itemID
1       101
1       103
1       107
2       102
2       103
3       104', header=T)

cat(sapply(split(d, d$userID), function(x) 
  paste(x$userID[1], paste(x$itemID, collapse=' , '), sep='\t')), 
  sep='\n', file='output.txt')
```

See `?cat` and `?paste` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another base solution using `aggregate`:

```
> write.table(aggregate(d$itemID, list(d$userID), paste, collapse=' , '),
              file='result.txt', sep='\t', col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
1       101 , 103 , 107
2       102 , 103
3       104
```